# $(B\mathbb Z/p^{\infty})^{\wedge}_p\rightarrow (BS^1)^{\wedge}_p$ induced by inclusion is an equivalence

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, classifying-spaces, bousfield-localization

Let $\mathbb{Z}/p^{\infty}$ denote the Prufer group. By $p$-completion properties, it follows that $(B\mathbb Z/p^{\infty})^{\wedge}_p\simeq K(\mathbb{Z}^{\wedge}_p,2)\simeq(BS^1)^{\wedge}_p$. But, why does the inclusion $\mathbb{Z}/p^{\infty}\hookrightarrow S^1$ induce such a homotopy equivalence?.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Think of the Prüfer group as $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ and of $S^1$ as $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$. Here $\mathbb{Q}$ is discrete, $\mathbb{R}$ has its usual topology and is contracible. The map $\mathbb{Q} \to\mathbb{R} $ becomes an equivalence after $p$-completion.

Comment: Thank you!, do you mean $B\mathbb{Q}^{\wedge}_p\rightarrow B\mathbb{R}^{\wedge}_p$ is a homotopy equivalence?

Comment: Yes, I think if you want to turn this idea into an actual proof you look at the induced map of fiber sequences $B\mathbb{Q}\to B\mathbb{Q/Z} \to K(Z,2)$ and $B\mathbb{R}\to B\mathbb{S^1}\to K(Z,2)$, and observe that the map on the fibers becomes an equivalence after $p$-completion.

Comment: but $B\mathbb{R}$ is contractible, and $B\mathbb{Q}$ is $p$-good. So far, their $p$-completions cannot be homotopy equivalent.

Comment: I'm not sure I correctly remember what $p$-good means, but note that the mod $p$ homology of $B\mathbb{Q}$ is of course zero.

Comment: Fine!, I was wrong, sorry. Thank you again.